# Import 3D model from maya to JOGL

Tags: java, jogl, maya

I want to know how is it possible to import just a 3D model from maya to JOGL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JOGL is a wrapper around the OpenGL API. It is very low-level. JOGL does not deal with 3D models, it just deals with things such as vertices and triangles. It's up to you to organize these things into 3D models - in other words, if you're using JOGL you'll have to program the managing of complete models all yourself.

So, to use a 3D model from Maya or any other 3D modelling tool in your JOGL program, you'll have to create classes to hold the information about the model yourself and you'll need to write some code (or use some other library) to load the model from a file.